Error when binding parameters to a quantum circuit
When I try to run the circuit below:
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal 
from math import pi

reference_circuit = TwoLocal(2, "rx", "cz", entanglement="linear", reps=1) theta_list = [pi / 2, pi / 3, pi / 3, pi / 2]

reference_circuit = reference_circuit.bind_parameters(theta_list)

reference_circuit.decompose().draw("mpl")

I get an error that says: 'TwoLocal' object has no attribute 'bind_parameters'. This code was working perfectly fine sometime ago but now it keeps throwing error.

You are getting that error because you are trying to run qiskit code written in qiskit<=0.46 in an environment that runs qiskit>=1.0.0. To fix this issue instead of using bind_parameters() use the new function assign_parameters(). So your code will look like:
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal 
from math import pi

reference_circuit = TwoLocal(2, "rx", "cz", entanglement="linear", reps=1) 
theta_list = [pi / 2, pi / 3, pi / 3, pi / 2]

reference_circuit = reference_circuit.assign_parameters(theta_list)

reference_circuit.decompose().draw("mpl")

For more information on the changes when migrating from qiskit<=0.46 to qiskit>=1.0.0 can be found here
